# Is there any function to do login action in CKAN without API call

Tags: python, ckan

Ideally how login works in CKAN as per `who.ini` [configuration](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/ckan-2.8.4/ckan/config/who.ini#L9) and [code](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/ckan-2.8.4/ckan/views/user.py#L373) is:

```
[plugin:friendlyform]
use = ckan.lib.repoze_plugins.friendly_form:FriendlyFormPlugin
login_form_url= /user/login
login_handler_path = /login_generic
```

Here `login_handler_path` is responsible for login and in frontend side of CKAN, it makes POST request to `/login_generic` endpoint with `name` as username and `password`.

Right now I am trying to create one plugin, where I am trying to login via plugin itself (with some function) without having user to login via any form in frontend.

So is there any helper / action function which I can use so that I can login behind the scenes in CKAN plugin itself.

What I understand is that CKAN uses some [repoze cookie / API Headers](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/ckan-2.8.4/ckan/config/middleware/flask_app.py#L284) to identify if user is logged in or not. If I make use of normal POST requests in python code, then I won't be able to set these cookies or environment variables and if I try to do it manually then I fear it will break something.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I think you should try to use [IAuthFunctions](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html?highlight=login#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IAuthenticator) to override CKAN's built-in authentication. This interface allows custom authentication methods to be integrated into CKAN.

Comment: Hi @Zoran Pandovski, say I want to add reCAPTCHA to the login page, can I implement it with `identify()` in `IAuthFunctions`? Thanks!